# Java - Binary Search Node How do I check the object?

Tags: java, binary-tree

How can I do the test without error?

Because of that object can not be used in this operator?

i have error(in insert function) why?

The error:

The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object

```
public class BinarySearchNode {
protected Object data;

protected BinarySearchNode left;
protected BinarySearchNode right;

public BinarySearchNode(Object data) {
    if (data == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("we are too lazy to deal with null data");

    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}

public void insert(Object toAdd) {
    if **(toAdd < data)** { <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here 
        if (left == null)
            left = new BinarySearchNode(toAdd);
        else
            left.insert(toAdd);
    } else {
        if (right == null)
            right = new BinarySearchNode(toAdd);
        else
            right.insert(toAdd);

    }
}

public void InOrderPrint() {
    if (left != null)
        left.InOrderPrint();

    System.out.println(this.data);

    if (right != null)
        right.InOrderPrint();

}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two approaches to establishing an order of `Object`s:

- **Replace `Object` with [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)** - this would let you put the comparison logic into the object itself, or
- **Ask the caller to supply an implementation of [`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)** - this would let your callers supply the logic directly when using your APIs.

Here is how you would use the first approach:

```
public class BinarySearchNode<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    protected T data;
    ...
    public void insert(T toAdd) {
        if (toAdd.compareTo(data) < 0) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **<** (*less then*) operator is a [relational operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) and it works only with numerical values.
It can work with the objects derived from [java.lang.Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), but before to perform the comparison, the compiler "makes" an [automatic unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) operation.